weird strips while trying to put material on a bottle
I am trying to put a plastic material on a simple bottle, but for some reason it gets these weird strips going. Its a very simple model, contains a mesh inside that is supposed to be liquid. Its the same plastic material that the yellow bottle has, but yellow bottle doesnt have the stips... I tried moving the bottle to another place in the scene to check that maybe the lighting is the problem, didnt help. I tried removing the 'liquid' inside and still got the same strips. So apparently something is wrong with the bottle, but its a very simple model so I have no idea what could have gone wrong, Please,help 

Can you share your Blender project file? Instructions for sharing.

At first I would say duplicate geometry or inverted face normals. But hard to tell from the screenshot, so I agree with @Jakemoyo that it probably be good to upload the file.
